# Why does footer not go all the way to the bottom?

Tags: css

I have a web page as follows:
http://www.transeeq.com/health/bq17a.html#

The yellowish footer does not get pushed all the way to the bottom. Any ideas? Here is the CSS code:

```
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}

#body {
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}

#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;          /* Height of the footer */
   background:#CCCC66;
}
```

Comment: As a purely HTML/CSS design question, this belongs on doctype.com

Comment: Do you mean to say it doesn't extend to the bottom when you must scroll to view all content?

Comment: @BobMcGee: HTML/CSS questions do belong here. DocType isn't affiliated to StackOverflow and questions like this one do have a place here.

Comment: @Andrew:  From the site FAQ: "If your question is about [...] web design and HTML/CSS layout, and your job title is "designer", ask on Doctype."  I don't think it could be any more clear-cut than that.

Comment: @BobMcGee: Let me highlight the keywords for you... "... **and your job title is 'designer'** ..."

Answer (score 1):

It works; your CSS is probably being cached locally. Have you done a forced browser refresh lately? Hit Ctrl+F5.

Answer (score 1):

[I use this css.](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/)

```css
* {
       margin: 0;
}
html, body {
       height: 96%;
}
.wrapper {
       min-height: 96%;
       height: auto !important;
       height: 96%;
       margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
.footer, .push {
       height: 4em;
}
```

And you can use it in your html page like this

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" ... />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <p>Your website content here.</p>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works very well in IE AND Firefox

Comment: @brasofilo It's an old answer ;-)  I edit it to add essential informations.

Comment: The answer showed up on the Low Quality Posts review. Someone may have flagged it. Looks good now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try the CSS code to achieve a "sticky footer" (per  http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it; it extends to the bottom in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, IE8, IE7, and even IE6. In which browser do you experience this problem, and can you describe your problem in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried floating the footer to the bottom and changing the position to relative?

Answer (score 0):

You have "height: 60px;" in #footer. Try making that a smaller number in the .css.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `footer` inside the `container` div - if you want to have the footer at the bottom of the page (not the bottom of a window) using position:absolute, you need to put it in a relatively positioned div, such as your container.

Have a look at [this article](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Answer (score -1):

Try `position: fixed` on the footer instead if you want to ensure that it's always at the bottom of the window.  Otherwise, to ensure it's always at the bottom of the document, you can keep its position as relative/auto.